# explicit instantiation with default template/function arguments

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I'm trying to explicitly instantiate a templated function that has a default template argument as well as a default value for the corresponding parameter but I can't find the right syntax. What I'm trying is the following:

```
// in .hpp
template<typename T = std::function<void(int,int)>> void foo (T &&t = [](int,int)->void{});
//in .cpp
template<typename T> void foo (T t){...}
template void foo<>();
```

But I just get an error saying foo<> does not match any template declaration. Is there any way to use default type and argument values while still being able to do an explicit instantiation? The only other option for me would be to either define the whole function in the header which I would prefer no to do or to give up on having default values.

Comment: Not directly related: putting a template definition in a .cpp file is a bad idea, and practically makes it usable only within that file. No other file can include the .hpp and really use the generic part of that template definition.

Comment: @chi - Unless one wishes to expose only a small set of types by explicit instantiation... exactly like the OP.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Indeed. The explicit instantiation the OP wants will work. However, I am concerned by the `template<typename T> void foo (T t){...}` part in the .cpp, which is pointless unless the OP also instantiates that. I can't understand if the OP really plans to add all the instances manually in the .cpp (which is OK), of if they wanted only an explicit instance for the default `T`, but they still expect the generic part to work (it won't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not keep the signature consistent. The declaration in the header accepts by rvalue reference, the implementation file by value, and the instantiation is for a function with absolutely no parameters (a default argument doesn't mean a function has no parameters).

You need to stick to the same signature everywhere.

So either

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T = std::function<void(int,int)>> void foo (T &&t = [](int,int)->void{});
//in .cpp
template<typename T> void foo (T&&){}

template void foo<>(std::function<void(int,int)>&&);
```

Or

```
#include <functional>

template<typename T = std::function<void(int,int)>> void foo (T t = [](int,int)->void{});
//in .cpp
template<typename T> void foo (T){}

template void foo<>(std::function<void(int,int)>);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Is there even any reason to have a default value of a parameter that is of a different type than then default value of a typename? It seems like instantiating it with the type of the default value for the parameter would always overwrite the default value for the typename. Default typenames in general would only make sense to me if I could completely leave the bracket empty for this example in the instantiation. But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @diesmond - You can call `foo()`. So it's usable. Whether or not it makes sense depends on your goal.

Comment: I think I got it. It seems a default argument goes hand in hand with a default type. I thought we might have a default argument from which a default type is implied but not explicitly written.

Comment: @diesmond - Default function arguments do not participate in template argument deduction.